# Dying for Caesar

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Smoothening the rest of the day? (7)
>   8. Tune's introduction omitted by exotic Croatian instrument (7)
>   10. Secretly agree to meet… (5)
>   13. …and not to be indoors every second (3)
>   14. Wanting starters? Appetizer? Apple, for example? (4)
>   16. Listen, know anyone who yearns? Not anymore? (2, 6)
>   17. Biblical figure is the first in importance, after God (3)
>   18/21. Apes get small Ford truck abruptly transformed into rocking record-breaker (8,3,11)
>   24. Die for Caesar, having no final drink (3)
>   26. Empire's ruler (a Poland native) accepted by no nation's leader (8)
>   28. Ship's personnel pulling out king from damaged wreck (4)
>   31. Drink from Mexico's capital used in Peruvian bank note (3)
>   32. Like Christopher Columbus lacked no proficient navigators (5)
>   34. As official loses, very loud campaigners essentially become insensitive (7)
>   35. Glide over snow among some retired people in the Arctic (7)
>
> **Down**
>   1. End of line – cross it, making way out (4)
>   2. Advantage from end game in an extreme way (4)
>   3. Chilling stuff – *Of Mice and Men*'s opening censored (3)
>   4. Reliable guide offered to opposition leaders (2-2)
>   5. Bribe scanal – finalist is ejected from decisive game (3-3)
>   6. Point out fringe characters (6)
>   7. Exuberant "Roaring Twenties'" end inside army territory (8)
>   9. Coward? "Professional" hitman seen retreating (4)
>   11. Generate crooked shed at cop out (6)
>   12. Listen up! Join the military (6)
>   15. Jay-Z's music criticism (3)
>   18. A river and U.S. state! (8)
>   19. At first, Incitatus gets mixed up with Queen of Horses (6)
>   20. Study of light topics at sea (6)
>   21. Set up plan to get behind the borders of Delaware (6)
>   22. Odd spill by a queen (6)
>   23. Travelled by horse, missing introduction to poem (3)
>   25. Asian people's historical era to progress finally (4)
>   27. Go back before the French look (4)
>   29. Five hundred sheets, with the state having destroyed fifty (4)
>   30. Temples covered in shadow at sunset (4)
>   33. Hotelkeeper keeping a wild animal (3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Explanations:

Across:

> 1. double def.  8. (CROA(-T)IA)*.  10. substring.  13. iNdOoRs.  14. (-en)TREE.  16. homophone of KNOW plus LONG-ER.  17. EL+I(-mportance).  18/21. APES containing PETITE FORD + TRUC(-k) + INTO*.  24. ALE(-a).  26. A POLE in NO N(-ation).  28. (WREC(-k))*.  31. double def. 32. GE(-no)ESE.  34. ASO(-ff)(-i)CIAL.  35. SKI in SOME<.

Down:

> 1. (-lin)E X IT.  2. E(n)D G(am)E.  3. MICE minus M(-en).  4. initial letters.  5. PLAYOFF - (-scanda)L.  6. FRINGE*.  7. ROARING* containing (-twentie)S.  9. LEON<.  11. (GENERATE-AT)*.  12. LISTEN*.  15. double def.  18. A R KANSAS &lit.  19. (I+QUEEN)*.  20. TOPICS*.  21. PLOY after D(-elawar)E.  22. S(-p)I(-l)L + VIA.  23. (-r)ODE.  25. (-historica)L (-er)A (-t)O (-progres)S. 27. GO< + LE.  29. REA(-l)M.  30. substring.  33. substring.

Credit where due: PiIsNot3 figured out 25d and 31a.

Comment: 25D could be rot13(\_Y + \_N + \_B + \_F, qrs "Nfvna crbcyr.") 31A might be rot13(n qbhoyr qrsvavgvba) given [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peruvian_sol) and [this](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/57/2803/), but I'm not too sure about it

Comment: Duh, you're obviously right about 25d. I think you're also right about 31a; I hadn't known about the beer.